# Perform calculations on a list of variables in SASS

Tags: loops, sass

Is it possible to perform calculations on a list of variables, to generate another list of variables.

E.g. say I want to list all the media queries I'd like to use in my CSS...

```
$mediaQueries:
768,
1024
;
```

And then double the value of all of these like so...

```
$newMediaQueries:

@each $mediaQuery in $mediaQueries {
  $mediaQuery * 2
}

;
```

(what I'd actually like to do is generate em versions for this list of variables but I thought I'd keep the maths simple for this example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
$mediaQueries: 768, 1024;

$newMediaQueries: ();

@each $mediaQuery in $mediaQueries {
  $newMediaQueries: append($newMediaQueries, $mediaQuery * 2);
}
```

The trick is to create an empty list and then iterate through the old values and append them to that new list.

By default it will output a list like `1536 2048`, but you can use commas by passing that option: `$newMediaQueries: append($newMediaQueries, $mediaQuery * 2, comma);`

Comment: so so awesome, I would have never figured that out, thank you bookcasey!